# Azure function to read a blob schema

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I am currently making a Azure Function that read a blob schema whenever a new file is uploaded. I use the Blob Trigger Function for it to trigger whenever a new file is uploaded, but from there I'm stuck. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code for Blod trigger to read data. Review your code with this which might help you in resolving the issue.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "queueName": "myqueue-items",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "name": "queuemsg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}-Copy",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py"
}
```

Here is the sample python code.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


# The input binding field inputblob can either be 'bytes' or 'str' depends
# on dataType in function.json, 'binary' or 'string'.
def main(queuemsg: func.QueueMessage, inputblob: bytes) -> bytes:
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    return inputblob
```

For complete information check this [Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp) documentation and [Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python) input binding.